# If automatic app updates are disabled on an iOS device, how often does the App Store update its app badge to show the number of available updates?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Assuming that automatic app updates are disabled on an iOS device, how often does the App Store check for app updates and update its app badge to show the number of updates that are available to be installed?